# How to "shrink wrap" a div around it's floated children

Tags: javascript, html, css, e-commerce

I'm working on a shopping cart site and trying to make the search results responsive.  Anything lower than a desktop resolution I would like the results to be as many items as can fit across (in most cases 3) and I want them to be centered, all the way down to a phone.

The issue that I am running into is that I can not seem to get the parent div to be the same width as its children, nor can I center it.

I have tried `display: inline-block` and that gives dimensions to the div, but it takes up 100% of the width.

Here is an example of what I am running in to:

http://jsfiddle.net/0jnjum30/1/

Has anyone accomplished anything like this before?  If at all possible I would like to do this entirely in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because inline elements don't have a width. You should make your children inline-blocks and not the parent. Once your parent has a width, you can center it.

```
.parent {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;    
}

.child {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
}
```

If updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gez46x0b/1/ The extra wrapper is necessary for having a centered list with the last element being aligned left.

Comment: Ya, I was afraid of that, it's hard for me to do inline-block on the child elements because they have overlays which are positioned absolutely and things get really wonky when I do that.  I'll try to figure out a way using the inline-block though, thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is the problem with inline-blocks and absolutely positioned overlays? After all the inline-blocks will behave like blocks. Having a single inline-block parent doesn't make sense. What makes your children float is the `float: left`

Comment: The problem is for some reason when they are inline-block and you hover over them (to cause the overlay to show up) they move up about 20 pixels, so every one that gets hovered over moves and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Sounds like a box sizing problem (margins, padding, height, width). Is this what you wanna do? http://jsfiddle.net/gez46x0b/2/ ? Did the example solve your specific problem (centering the div an having a width)?

Comment: Okay, I looked at your fiddle, and that is what I want to achieve.  The only thing is I don't want to specify a width on the parent container, I just always want it to be as wide as the children.

Comment: Then just change the width of the parent container to 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/gez46x0b/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68439/discussion-between-brandon-shega-and-stekhn).